# Local network proxy server

Tags: proxy, home-networking, internet-connection

I'm looking for a proxy server to allow other users on my network to connect through my computer's 3G modem connection.

Preferably I don't want to have to go through a ton of settings to get it working either. I don't care about which ports are being used, whatever data/ports the computers on the network request, it should be done and the reply sent back to them.

Currently I'm using AnalogX proxy, but is there a better system available? Currently all the computers on my home network run Windows 7.

Thanks.

Comment: just to be clear - do you want a caching proxy to cut back on bandwidth use or something else? What exactly are the places where your current proxy fails?

Comment: It's a mission to share my internet connection given that I have a 3G dongle (USB) and so I use a proxy on my computer, through which the other computers on the network connect. Currently the proxy fails to log in to some sites, minecraft servers, etc. (I.e., the only reason I want a proxy is to share my internet connection.)

Comment: Whats the purpose of your proxy here? Windows can act as a gateway/router/dhcp server with ICS - you'd be looking at a proxy for filtering or caching in this case wouldn't you?

Comment: I have a router which serves as the DHCP server. Preferably I don't want my computer to be the DHCP server, and afaik that's the only way to share a 3G connection using Windows ICS.

Comment: hmm, wierd topology, but i suppose that'll work.

Comment: If I could find out why AnalogX Proxy fails to submit/receive certain data packets I could probably stick with it. It seems like passing credentials (on some sites) get stuck somewhere or don't reach the server. Also (the latest problem), network computers cannot reach the Minecraft servers via the proxy.